# OnClickListener doesn't fire

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener

**The problem**

This code doesn't fire when the button is clicked.

```
mBtnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    mBtnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            mTest= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
            mTest.setText("hello");

        }
    });
```

The previous code is inside:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

In *MainActivity.java* after  *setContentView(R.layout.main);*

Both variables for button and EditText are declared here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IToolbarsContainer, OnTouchListener, IDownloadEventsListener {
    private Button mBotonEnviar;
    private EditText mCampoPrueba;
```

And i have:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

This is the complete layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="org.cade.codigos.ui.activities.RequestData">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Titulo"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitiulo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Nombre"
    android:id="@+id/lblNombre"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitiulo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Nombre"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblNombre"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Apellido"
    android:id="@+id/lblApellido"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Apellido"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtApellido"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblApellido"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send"
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

**Long.. onCreate method for request**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);              

    INSTANCE = this;

    Constants.initializeConstantsFromResources(this);

    Controller.getInstance().setPreferences(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));       

    if (Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_SHOW_FULL_SCREEN, false)) {          
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    if (Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_GENERAL_HIDE_TITLE_BARS, true)) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }



    setProgressBarVisibility(true);

    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_request_data);

    mBotonEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
    mBotonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            mCampoPrueba = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtApellido);
            mCampoPrueba.setText("hola");

        }
    });

    mCircularProgress = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spinner);

    EventController.getInstance().addDownloadListener(this);                

    mHideToolbarsRunnable = null;

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    buildComponents();                

    mViewFlipper.removeAllViews();   

    updateSwitchTabsMethod();
    updateBookmarksDatabaseSource();

    registerPreferenceChangeListener();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.getData() != null) {
        // App first launch from another app.
        addTab(false);
        navigateToUrl(i.getDataString());
    } else {
        // Normal start.
        int currentVersionCode = ApplicationUtils.getApplicationVersionCode(this);
        int savedVersionCode = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(Constants.PREFERENCES_LAST_VERSION_CODE, -1);

        // If currentVersionCode and savedVersionCode are different, the application has been updated.
        if (currentVersionCode != savedVersionCode) {
            // Save current version code.
            Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.putInt(Constants.PREFERENCES_LAST_VERSION_CODE, currentVersionCode);
            editor.commit();

            // Display changelog dialog.
            Intent changelogIntent = new Intent(this, ChangelogActivity.class);
            startActivity(changelogIntent);
        }




        /*
        if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_BROWSER_RESTORE_LAST_PAGE, false)) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {               
                String savedUrl = savedInstanceState.getString(Constants.EXTRA_SAVED_URL);
                if (savedUrl != null) {
                    addTab(false);
                    navigateToUrl(savedUrl);
                    lastPageRestored = true;
                }
            }
        }*/

        boolean lastPageRestored = false;
        // gaf - comienzo con la pagina inicial
        String savedUrl = "file:///android_asset/startpage/index.html";
        //String savedUrl = "http://servidor-cade.com";
        //String savedUrl = "http://192.168.1.18:3636";
        addTab(false);
        navigateToUrl(savedUrl);
        lastPageRestored = false;

        //if (!lastPageRestored) {
        //  addTab(true);
        //}
    }

    initializeWebIconDatabase();

    startToolbarsHideRunnable();



}
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside the onClick method, the code doesn't get there at all? Btw mBtnSend and mTest arn't defined in the code you've attached

Comment: Post your complete main layout please.

Comment: Are you sure that `R.id.btnSend` is inside the view where you're calling `findViewById`?

Comment: I am calling findViewById inside MainActivity.java and the Button is inside activity_request_data.xml

Comment: why are you calling setContentView() with R.layout.main and not R.layout. activity_request_data ?

Comment: there is no EditText view in your XML that has the id "txtText"

Comment: I am guessing your `OnTouchListener` interface is blocking your clickListener from working, so post more of the onCreate method,

Answer (score 0):

Where is btnEnviar?
Take the findViewById(R.id.txtApellido); out of the listener.
Maybe try this:

```
mCampoPrueba = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtApellido);
mBotonEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
    mBotonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
                            mCampoPrueba.setText("hola");

        }
    });
```

Comment: its btnSend , i changed the name to english so you would understand in the xml, dont worry no problems of names

Comment: Did you take findViewById out of the onClick?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must initialize mTest in onCreate method, because when you created a listener you created new anonymus object. If you whan to relete to object in MainActivity you must call:

`mTest= (EditText) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.txtText)`

Answer (score 0):

Layout file don't have Button with `R.id.btnEnviar`. Did you mean: `R.id.btnSend`

```
mCampoPrueba = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtApellido);
mBotonEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    mBotonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
           mCampoPrueba.setText("hola");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

***The problem was i was writing code in the wrong activity due to my lack of knowledge, thank you very much everyone!***